# postfix - handling forwards

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to send mails addressed to a subdomain/server sub1.abc.com of our domain abc.com.
This domain is handled by a central postfix mail server configured by means of sql.
Although the transport table has an entry to relay all mails for sub1.abc.com to that smtp address, main.cf holds a relay_domains entry for sub1.abc.com and dns knows sub1.abc.com and its smtp mx entry postfix keeps looping back to itself.

Edit: I tried the entries for transport, mydestination and relay_domains separately but the result was always the same.

Where can I set this routing entry?

Comment: attach the output of: 'postconf -n'

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

Create a transport file and put something like this in it:

```
username@example.com relay:[subdomain.example.com]
```

Update main.cf and add:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

By the way, this sounds more like an error in routing rather than a postfix error (but make sure you do not list your subdomain in mydestination in the main.cf file)

Be sure to use your own ip address and subdomain record.

Comment: I just tried this out without having relay_domains and it failed.

Comment: I see what jamespo is saying.  He's correct.  The relay in in the transport map.

Answer (score -1):

you do not need the subdomain in relay_domains for a start if you have a transport entry for it